# How can I assign a pointer to another in MIPS? (From C to MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int split_str(char ** solution, char * str, const dictionary * dict){
    char * ptr = str;
    (more code here...)
}
```

How would I go about "initializing" ptr in MIPS? Would I use "move", "lw", or "sw"?

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
sub $sp, $sp, 16
sw $ra, 0($sp) 
sw $s0, 4($sp) 
sw $s1, 8($sp)
sw $s2, 12($sp)

move $s0, $a0   # solution in $s0
move $s1, $a1   # str in $s1
move $s2, $a2   # dict in $s2

(...etc.)
```

Comment: Depends on where you allocated it. If you assigned a register, you use `move`. If you allocated it on the stack, you use `sw`.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing which ABI you're using (specifically, how function arguments are passed).

Comment: `str` is in `$a1`, what you do is copy it from `$a1` to `$s1` (so `$s1` is `ptr`) and that's fine. Or do you have some problem?

Comment: @Jester : I need to use $a1 for other things later in the program which is why I moved str to $s1. I then need to use ptr (which has its value initialized to str so char *ptr = str) and str at the same time in a function call. So in this case, would I use move to put ptr in a register? Or would I use lw/sw?

Comment: That depends on where you allocate it, as I said. If you allocate it another register, say `$s3` then you can `move`. If you allocate it on the stack, then you `sw`.

Answer (score 0):

char * str is nothing but the address to wherever str is in memory. char * ptr therefore holds the same address to str after you assign pointer to str to pointer to ptr. simply move the value stored in the register that holds the pointer to str to the new register that represents pointer to ptr.

suppose you want to store the pointer to ptr in $t0 and pointer to str is stored in $a1, this code will do the trick: `move   $t0, a1`